# I can't figure out why there is so much empty space?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to remove all the extra space at the bottom of [this page](http://www.uteznvanz.com.au/index.html).  I am a beginner at web design and it probably shows, I only know HTML and CSS and then only a little, but any help with where I have gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Matt i thought it would have been a bit much to post the entire css file, and really im not sure why i have ended up with so much empty space at the bottom of the page in question, i also check how it looks in the 5 main browsers as well as mobile browsers so i know the problem is in the layout somewhere

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post such thing, but I would recommend to check your hosting, as everything loads extremely slowly, while I'm having real 3-5MByte/s speed. Either big images or slow hosting. As I see you already have the correct answer. Good luck with your site. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have images within 'p' tags that are position:relative; that needs to be updated appropriately they are currently not visible at the bottom, but taking up space at the bottom of the page.They are the button images at the top right.

Example:
adoptaroadwork.png

You'll need to check your design and css to fix this issue.

Comment: Using position, relative, absolute, fixed, and static is fine but you need to keep in mind where these elements(div,p) are in the html structure and based off that create your css styles. I can't do the design for you but understanding how elements are laid out by default should help you fix this issue.

Comment: You should use such positions but use them wisely.

Comment: Thanx Cocre8or, looks like i need to do some more reading! But you have given me some good ideas to work with thanks again!

Comment: I would suggest wrapping those buttons in a div of their own and positioning the div first.

Comment: thats what im after, beauty m8, ill report back in a couple of days i drive a truck part time to make a living :-P